# Getting the value of the jtextfield and put it to label in another form

Tags: java, netbeans, jlabel, jtextfield

I have Jtextfield in one form and I want to get the value that I typed and put it in Jlabel in the other form? How can I do that?

Comment: post the code you tried with

Answer (score 1):

To get the text:

```
String text = textField.getText();
```

And then set it on your label with

```
label.setText(text);
```

Comment: My label is in the other form how can i set it?